# Check if cell is text and if so, delete row

Tags: excel, vba, loops, row

UPDATE:

Data set is made of strings that are number though (I don't get it) -> I can do all the math stuff with them as with regular numbers.

Problem is I need to separate cells that look like this "186.85" and cells that look like this "1.76 Dividend".

====================

I need a loop to check row by row if the cell contains some text (word "dividend" specifically) or if it's just number. If it is a text, then delete it and move to the next row.

It does some deleting BUT it wipes like 50 rows of data almost every time (I have only two text populated rows in this particular data set). These rows are numbers.

```
Dim i As Long
i = 2

Do
    If WorksheetFunction.IsText(Sheets("Data").Cells(i, 5)) = True Then
        If Not Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 5).Value = "" Then
            Worksheets("Data").Rows(i).Delete
        End If
    End If
    i = i + 1
Loop Until i = 100
```

I expected to loop through the data and delete the entire row if a cell contains text.

This code so far deletes things kinda randomly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below has been updated to a dynamic range. This will not need modification regardless of how many rows your sheet has.

More importantly, deleting rows inside a loop will cause your range to shift at every deletion. The way around this is to loop backwards

### OR, even better..

Don't delete cells inside your loop. Every time your criteria is met, you force an action (deletion). Instead, gather up all of the cells to be deleted inside your loop and then delete the entire collection (`Union`) all at once outside of the loop. This requires 1 action in total rather 1 action per text instance

---

```
Sub Looper()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") '<-- Update sheet name
Dim i As Long, LR As Long
Dim DeleteMe As Range

LR = ws.Range("E" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To LR
    If WorksheetFunction.IsText((ws.Range("E" & i))) Then
        If Not DeleteMe Is Nothing Then
            Set DeleteMe = Union(DeleteMe, ws.Range("E" & i))
        Else
            Set DeleteMe = ws.Range("E" & i)
        End If
    End If
Next i

If Not DeleteMe Is Nothing Then DeleteMe.EntireRow.Delete

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
Sub test()

    Dim i As Long

    For i = 100 To 2 Step -1

        With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")


            If WorksheetFunction.IsText(.Cells(i, 5)) = True Then

                If Not .Cells(i, 5).Value = "" Then
                    .Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
                End If

            End If

        End With

    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. Unfortunately, this still deletes half of data set every time I run it :/

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SpecialCells` with `xlCellTypeConstants-2`... No need for a loop. See [Range.SpecialCells method (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.specialcells) and [XlSpecialCellsValue enumeration (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlspecialcellsvalue)

Is this what you are trying?

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range

    '~~> Change this to the relevant sheet
    Set ws = Sheet1

    With ws
        On Error Resume Next
        Set rng = .Columns(5).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 2)
        On Error GoTo 0

        If Not rng Is Nothing Then rng.EntireRow.Delete
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for quick responses and effort.

I managed to get this solution working with InStr() function:

```
''loop through the Data and remove all rows containing text (Dividend payments which we don't need)

Dim i As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim searchText As String
Dim searchString As String

    i = 2
Set ws = Sheets("Data")


Do Until ws.Cells(i, 2).Value = ""

    searchText = "Dividend"
    searchString = ws.Cells(i, 2).Value

        If InStr(searchString, searchText) Then
            ws.Rows(i).Delete
        End If

        i = i + 1
Loop
```

Comment: To indicate the question has been solved, accept an answer. https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer. Consider removing solved from the title of the question.